# Duplicate video files in WhatsApp Sent items

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

Is there any scenario where WhatsApp copies video twice in sent items (with different sizes) that was sent to the single recipient? I had a scenario where I am sure I have sent the video to single user, during the sent operation I got Retry options for few times ( due to disk was full and/or for network) so I remember I have retried 3-4 times to deliver that message, but now I can see two copies of the same video with different sizes. Is this scenario possible to occur or have I sent to another user by mistake. Cant check because later I have changed by phone losing all messages history.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible that the file failed in the middle of uploading for some reason and the uploaded part remained as an incomplete file in your sent items. Then when you sent the file again, instead of resuming the upload, a complete file was resent seperately. I'm not a 100% sure but it is possible.